# Laravel - clean session issue

Tags: php, laravel

I store data like 'card' in session. I'm routing the route and clearing the session. After doing the cleanup, it logs out the authenticated user. I don't know much about session, I just started using it, but this bug that I experienced felt a little illogical.

Where am I missing?

```
if ($myResponse->response->accepted == 1) {
        session()->forget('card');
        if(!Auth::check()){
          session()->forget('shippingAddress');
        }
        return redirect()->route('myOrders')->with('success','success');
```

Comment: I tried your code locally, and no issues; it forgot the Session Keys (or does nothing if they're not present), then redirects to the specified route. Question though, why the `!Auth::check()`? That will only be `true` if no one is logged in, but if you're complaining about them being logged out, you have conflicting expectations vs the code you're writing... I think you might need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74047869/edit) and include more code/clarify your problem.

Comment: actually the part you mentioned is not very important because I am making a check for those who are not logged in. you can ignore the part you mentioned

Comment: Fair enough, but even still; I was not able to reproduce your issue... There is nothing in the code you posted that would cause the authenticated User to be logged out consistently; is there any more code associated with this, or no?

Comment: unfortunately that's all the code is. this is what makes no sense. i'm facing a meaningless problem even though i haven't done anything else related to the session.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea then... There has to be something else going on in your code that is causing this issue... Sorry 